# High chart -override legend click and hover event to custom logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Highchart API is providing hover and click event over legend by out of the box. But i want to customize that events.

Any trick is available with highchart to override that events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do this:

```
point: {
   events: {
        legendItemClick: function () {
             // function def
        }
   }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-point-events-legenditemclick/)

Comment: In Default behave, when we click on legend, it will be work as hide/show. correct? if i want to show at-least one legend enabled.